# Why does Express middleware require no return value?

Tags: node.js, express

An express middleware takes `req, res, next` as function arguments, but never returns anything. yet the modified `req, res` objects are available for the next middleware down the chain.

How is this achieved in Node? Are these variables global in scope?

Comment: They don't need to be global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express is designed for asynchronous request handlers.  So, it calls your request handler or middleware and passes it three things `(req, res, next)`.  These are all pointers.  The first two are pointers to an object, the 3rd is a function reference (essentially a pointer to a function).  The architecture of Express is that this request handler can do anything it wants, including lots of asynchronous stuff and then it should do one of three things:

1. Send a response such as `res.send(...)`
2. It can call `next()` and that will tell Express to continue routing by looking in the list of registered route handlers to see if there are any more route handlers that match the current request
3. It can call `next(err)` to indicate an error has occurred and Express will then route the request to an error handler.

When, a middleware function modifies `req` or `res`, they are modifying an object that Express has a reference to so if that middleware calls `next()`, the same object (with it's modifications) is passed to the next middleware in the chain.  This object doesn't need to be returned from the function because Express already has a reference to it (from when the whole request chain started).

Answer (score 1):

Objects in javascript are references. This means that if you pass in an object to one function and that function modifies it that object is modified. To put it another way, the object inside the function and the object passed into the function is the same object, not two objects that look alike.

Here's a very simple example of this:

```
var real_req = {};

function a (req) {
    req.hello = 'world';
    // I return nothing
}

function b (req) {
    console.log(req.hello);
}

a(real_req); // this method should add a new property "hello" to real_req
b(real_req); // this should print out "world"
```

All express has to do is pass the same object to all middlewares in a single request. Express will create a separate object for each request ensuring that middlewares don't accidentally mix up requests

Answer (score 0):

I understand your confusion. The answer is  straightforward. JS uses async i/o, so middleware in Express is designed to be used for both async and sync calls. To support both,  callbacks are used. Newer versions of Express will support async/await, but ultimately all async code in any language uses callbacks.

You register your callback functions, and your callback functions are called with 3 arguments: req, res, next. And next() itself is a callback function.